# How to keep external references to abstract generic class abstract and generic?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, abstract

I am trying to do something like the following -

```
public abstract class Utility<A, B>
{
    // Return values cannot be cached in class-scoped fields as these need to be invoked by threaded application
    public abstract A GetPrimaryData(float foo);
    public abstract B GetSecondaryData(float bar, A primaryData);

    public abstract float ProcessData(A primaryData, B secondaryData);
}

public class SpecificUtility : Utility<C, D>
{
    public override C GetPrimaryData(float foo) { /* implementation */ }

    public override D GetSecondaryData(float bar, C primaryData) { /* implementation */ }

    public override float ProcessData(C primaryData, D secondaryData) { /* implementation */ }
}

public class UserClass
{
    // Important - this script doesn't care what A or B is! Should be able to use ANY implementation of Utility.
    // As a result, we can't define UserClass as a generic of <A, B>
    public Utility<A, B> Utility;

    // This can be invoked in parallel for many tables concurrently
    public void UseCase(Table table)
    {
        // For performance reasons, retrieving utilPrimaryData in the inner loop is not feasible
        A utilPrimaryData = Utility.GetPrimaryData(GetFoo(table));

        var stuffUserCaresAbout = table.AsParallel().ForAll(row =>
        {
            B utilSecondaryData = Utility.GetSecondaryData(GetBar(row), utilPrimaryData);
            return Utility.ProcessData(utilPrimaryData, utilSecondaryData);
        });

        Consume(stuffUserCaresAbout);
    }
}
```

I was thinking of making an `IUtility` interface that `Utility` class implements, and the `UserClass` interacts with, but that doesn't actually address the issue because the `UserClass` needs to actually obtain the `PrimaryData` and `SecondaryData` that the `Utility` will then process into the value the User needs to work with.

The only solution I can think of would be to make `GetPrimaryData` and `GetSecondaryData` return generic Objects which would then be casted into the specific types that the `Utility` subclasses are expecting, but I find that very unsatisfying and suspect the performance implications would not be great either.

Comment: How is `UserClass` expected to obtain its `Utility`?

Comment: It's set from external code which is why the field is public. For example, maybe there are 3 different valid Utility implementations, and the end user can choose the one they wish to use from a dropdown menu. In that example, the GUI code would assign the relevant Utility to the User class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dynamic`:

```
    public object Utility;
    public void UseCase()
    {
        var util = (dynamic)Utility;
        dynamic utilPrimaryData = util.GetPrimaryData(GetFoo());
        dynamic utilSecondaryData = util.GetSecondaryData(GetBar(), utilPrimaryData);

        float dataUserActuallyCaresAbout = util.ProcessData(utilPrimaryData, utilSecondaryData);
    }
```

Just be aware that you'll lose all type safety for these calls, turning any mistakes with method names, etc. into a runtime error. To reduce the surface area of possible mistakes, you could extract most of this to a generic method that gets dynamically invoked:

```
    public object Utility;

    public void UseCase()
    {
        float dataUserActuallyCaresAbout = GetDataUserCaresAbout((dynamic)Utility, GetFoo(), GetBar());
    }
    private static float GetDataUserCaresAbout<A, B>(Utility<A, B> utility, float foo, float bar)
    {
        var utilPrimaryData = utility.GetPrimaryData(foo);
        var utilSecondaryData = utility.GetSecondaryData(bar, utilPrimaryData);

        return utility.ProcessData(utilPrimaryData, utilSecondaryData);
    }
```

You may want to consider moving this code into a context that does care about the generic types, though. For example, this code has a Feature Envy smell that might be addressed by giving `Utility` a method that handles these details with a non-generic signature:

```
public interface IUtility
{
    float GetDataUserCaresAbout(float foo, float bar);
}

public abstract class Utility<A, B> : IUtility
{
    public abstract A GetPrimaryData(float foo);
    public abstract B GetSecondaryData(float bar, A primaryData);

    public abstract float ProcessData(A primaryData, B secondaryData);

    public float GetDataUserCaresAbout(float foo, float bar)
    {
        var utilPrimaryData = GetPrimaryData(foo);
        var utilSecondaryData = GetSecondaryData(bar, utilPrimaryData);

        return ProcessData(utilPrimaryData, utilSecondaryData);
    }
}
```

```
    public IUtility Utility;

    public void UseCase()
    {
        float dataUserActuallyCaresAbout = Utility.GetDataUserCaresAbout(GetFoo(), GetBar());
        Console.WriteLine(dataUserActuallyCaresAbout);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

The latter suggestion sounds good but it wouldn't work for my particular use case. Maybe I should edit my question to make this clearer.

Essentially I need to invoke `Utility` in parallel across a huge body of data.

`PrimaryData` only needs to be retrieved once per table, whereas `SecondaryData` needs to be retrieved once per row. The flow of processing the data is controlled by the `User` which is why the `User` needs to be able to control when each data object is retrieved.

Comment: @JulianKantor I don't see how that substantially changes the feasibility of this approach, or of Riad's approach. `stuffUserCaresAbout` just becomes a collection rather than a scalar. But if your implementation details really prevent it from working, feel free to use `dynamic` or just cast `object`s like you said. The cast is unlikely to impact performance noticeably, and lots of perfectly good software is written in languages that don't offer type safety, no matter how unsatisfying it may feel.

Comment: In your example, GetPrimaryData() and GetSecondaryData() are invoked at the same time. The issue is that GetPrimaryData() needs to be invoked once for every 1000s of times that GetSecondaryData() is invoked, which your design would not permit. But yeah, I could go with the untyped route.

Comment: My `GetDataUserCaresAbout` method example could be changed to have your updated code (using `Select` instead of `ForAll`), and return an `IEnumerable<float>`. Having to invoke GetSecondaryData() many times for each GetPrimaryData() call doesn't fundamentally change the solution.

Comment: Not sure I get what you're saying entirely, but if I understand it correctly then you'd be moving the loop control logic inside of `Utility` rather than `User`? That sounds like a different solution to me but it could work, if I passed the bulk of the workload into Utility as Actions.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a controller interface and a controller generic class to implement abstract invocation of generic methods. Consider the following code:

```
    public abstract class Utility<A, B>
{
    public abstract A GetPrimaryData(float foo);
    public abstract B GetSecondaryData(float bar, A primaryData);
    public abstract float ProcessData(A primaryData, B secondaryData);
}

public class SpecificUtility<C, D> : Utility<C, D>
{
    public override C GetPrimaryData(float foo) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public override D GetSecondaryData(float bar, C primaryData) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public override float ProcessData(C primaryData, D secondaryData) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

public interface IUtilityController
{
    float UseCase(float a, float b);
}

public record class UtilityController<A, B>(Utility<A, B> utility) : IUtilityController
{
    public float UseCase(float a, float b)
    { // code that deals with A and B specific properties and methods
        A utilPrimaryData = utility.GetPrimaryData(a);
        B utilSecondaryData = utility.GetSecondaryData(b, utilPrimaryData);
        return utility.ProcessData(utilPrimaryData, utilSecondaryData);
    }
}

public class UserClass
{
    IUtilityController? _controller;
    public void SetController(IUtilityController c)
    {
        _controller = c;
    }
    
    public float? UseCase(float a, float b)
    { // code that deals with actual invocation of generic object invocation
        return _controller != null ? _controller.UseCase(a, b) : null;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This won't work for my specific use case because `GetSecondaryData` needs to be invoked many times for each invocation of `GetPrimaryData.` When I get a chance I will rework the question to better illustrate this point.